# ANGLE (OpenGL) windows.h missing / VS12

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, opengl-es, directx, angle

I'm tring to compile ANGLE with VS12 on W8 x64. The system was a clean install, so VS12 uses new configuration and not the VS10 config.

I set everything up according to their tutorial but VS is still not able to locate windows.h.
This is the tutorial I used: https://code.google.com/p/angleproject/wiki/DevSetup

> Error 4   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory   u:\angleproject\include\egl\eglplatform.h   74  1   libEGL

The project was created for VS10 and to compile it in VS12 I have to "upgrade it to VS12 configuration".

In a new VC++ projekt VS has no problem locating windows.h